# With numbers 1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 make an eight digit number ( without repeating ) so that it is divisible by 275?

Tags: combinatorics

Friends I was practicing some number arrangement-based questions of Permutations and Combinations.

In a question I am stuck with, please help me find a way out.

With numbers, $1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9$ make an eight-digit number ( without repeating ) so that it is divisible by $275$?

Comment: 1. What have you tried, how have you approached the problem ? 2. What divisibility rules have you learnt ?

Comment: I have tried to approach the problem by thinking about the unit digit no which must be 5 or 0.

Comment: Then as 0 is not given so we can only put 5.  Now 275 is 25*11.

Comment: So after putting 5 in unit's place we can put 7 in tenth place to make it divisible by 25 . By this logic in third place I have put 8 , . . . . .875  in this format 875 can be divided by 275 which gives 3. Now ?

Comment: ..75 is the only possible ending. But 275·5=1375, 275·9=2475, 275·17=4675, ... So ...875 is not the only possible ending.

Comment: Ending in 75 takes care of divisibility by 25 once and for all. What remains is divisibility by 11. Do you know how to tell from the digits of a number whether it's divisible by 11? Can you make that happen?

Comment: Ya that's right too.

Comment: Sum of all given digits is equal 43. It is not even. 43–11=32. 32/2=16. There are only one way to select four digits that add up to 16.

Comment: Digits on 1st,3rd,5th positions can be swapped arbitrarily. Digits on 2nd, 4th, 6th positions can be swapped arbitrarily. So there are 6·6=36 such eight digit numbers divisible by 275.

Comment: This question is freaking simple? i mean there's always such number given that you know the last 2 or 3 digits and then you just try them all out to see the divisibility for 11. Maybe it would be harder if you ask for the number of satisfying eight-digit integers?

Comment: @NikolaTolzsek Question is not simple unless you know (and are very confident in the knowledge that) [1] Odd digits minus even digits is multiple of $11$ and [2] last two digits must equal $75$.  Not unusual for poster to not have *confident* knowledge of these facts.

Comment: @user2661923 I'm just suggesting a more difficult question for someone who might be concerned. Should I make an edits down in my answer?

Comment: @NikolaTolzsek I'm not really sure.

Comment: I am just saying my approach , . . . . . 7 5 is the format for divisibility of 25 . Now we know that the divisibility by 11 rule states that if the difference of the sum of the digits at odd places and even places of the number is 0 or divisible by 11, then the given number is also divisible by 11.

Comment: So now we have to apply the divisibility rule of 11 for the remaining places , right ?

Comment: Ans is 36. The ans is given in the ans key but the process is not .

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your question, I would say: **$91368475$** is a solution. Very simple.

But since you are learning combination and permutation, I challenge you to the following expansion on the problem:

> Find the number of eight-digit integers, composed of the digits
> $1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9$ such that they are divisible by $275$.

For your reference I leave here some thoughts:

- The number is divisible by $25$, and thus must end on $00,25,50,75$, but there's no $0$ and $2$ so it ends on $75$,
- The sum of the digits is $43$. So the sum of digits at even places(denote as $\mathcal{E}$) - the sum of digits at odd places (denote as $\mathcal{O}$) equals $11$ or $33$.

But since $9+8+7+6=30 <33$, $|\mathcal{E}-\mathcal{O}|=11$

Now,

If $\mathcal{E}=27$ then find 3 digits add up to $22$ different from $5$ and $7$.

If $\mathcal {E}=16$ then find 3 digits add up to $11$ different from $5$ and $7$.

The remaining things are about permutations, let's see if you can solve it.

Regards,